# Add rows to numpy array not knowing shape - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I wanna set the number of columns with the number of elements of first row that is added in the loop and next add n new rows

In this example i want make an 3x3 matrix but i get an error

```
import numpy as np
import random 

ln1 = np.array([])
ln2 = np.array([])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        value = np.sin((random.randint(0, 50)))
        ln1 = np.append(ln1, value)
    ln2 = np.vstack((ln2, ln1))
    ln1 = np.array([])
```

i'm trying to do this

```
ln1 = []
ln2 = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        value = np.sin((random.randint(0, 50)))
        ln1.append(value)
    ln2.append(ln1)
    ln1 = []
```

but with numpy arrays. It's just a simple example to learn a little bit more about numpy and applied that in other more complex problem

Comment: why are you looping while working with numpy? do you need numpy for this? in the first pass in the inner loop, it's trying to stack an empty array with an array of shape 3x1.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? what are the rows are supposed to be filled with?

Comment: i did edit the post for more details

Comment: The list version is right.  As for the array version, have you learned anything from the error (which you forgot to show :(  )?  You may learn more from understanding the error than from us telling you the right way.

Comment: Did you look into setting all array values at once?  `np.sin(np.random.randint(0,50,(3,3)))`

Comment: You do know the shape - the 3 in both `range` calls.